# Google Chart Height in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

Im new using Google Chart API.

I'm using the simplest bar chart, I fill it when I fetch the data from a personal api. So, the problem is that, google gives me a default height for the google chart. So, when i push the fetched data into into the chartData, and the chart is rendered, 10 bars are rendered in like, 200px height, so, I get something like:

[image: Image here of the actual chart view]

I want to make the height dynamic, I mean, like it gets smaller whenever i put more data into the chartData. So what I want is to change height of the chart dynamic, so, what happen in the image wont happen.

Comment: Try setting `theme: 'maximized'` in `options`

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the answer, this works, but, then vAxis text will go over the line, and the hAxis % will be next the vertical line, not under

Comment: @TheMaster thanks again!! this does not work too, the problem is that, I want it to get bigger depending on the bars, I mean, If i hae ten bars, i dont want to have a chart like in theimage, i want it bigger, but, If i have 2 bars, i want it smaller. Hope you can understand me thanks!!

Comment: Not an expert on Google-visualization, someone else might be able to help. As a last try, try setting `chartArea: {width: '100%', height: '100%'}` in options

Comment: You could adjust the height option based on the number of rows in the data table, use method getNumberOfRows()